# psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres" (Ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

When I try to open `psql` with this command:

```
psql -U postgres
```

I get this error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

But it connects successfully when I use:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Can someone please explain what is happening and how to diagnose/fix this problem? My `pg_hba.conf` contains the following:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can edit your **.conf** files with privileges using an editor, for my case it is nano.

```
$sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_ident.conf
```

Map your user by adding this line

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
user1           <computer-username>     postgres
```

Replace the `<computer-username>` with the System-Username, which can be found using the **whoami** command. Type in your terminal:

```
$whoami
```

Then go ahead to the pg_hba.conf with privileges

```
$sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Add your postgres user, with method=peer, as shown below:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Changing `$sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf` the line `local   all             postgres                                peer` from `peer` to `trust` then `systemctl restart postgresql@14-main.service` it works for me.

Comment: I don't know what is the implication of the above solution but it worked for me thanks.

Comment: @RaghavendraAcharya editing the pg_hba.conf allows the user (postgres to authenticate or connect* with the database backend), the computer username is mapped with the allowed database user which is why you added it as a peer in the pg_ident.conf file. The connection parameter is localhost, which is handled locally in your machine.

Comment: `local   all             postgres                                md5`  
will make the password really work. `trust` mode will never ask for password.

Comment: It worked for me. However, don't forget to should reload the postgresql service to take effect.

Comment: I tried every solution on this page, but none has worked for me, I am still using `sudo -u postgres psql`

Answer (score 42):

[Peer authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-peer.html) means that the connection is only allowed if the name of the database user is the same as the name of the operating system user.

So if you run `psql -U postgres` as operating system user `root` or `jimmy`, it won't work.

You can specify a [mapping](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-username-maps.html) between operating system users and database users in `pg_ident.conf`.

Answer (score 9):

I was trying to make the answer about using /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_ident.conf work by adding a map like this:

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
user1             <computer-username>               postgres
```

Then adding the next code to /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

But that didn't work for me.
Then I read [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-username-maps.html) documentation and found the solution!
It's just a matter of adding a reference to the map to pg_hba.conf with map=user1:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             postgres                                peer map=user1
```

Comment: Thanks! After a lot of tries found your ans working, but there is a problem, After implementing your solution `sudo -u postgres` is not working any more it ask for ubuntu user password after giving password showing an error

Answer (score 4):

```html
step-1 
vi /etc/postgresql/14/main# vi postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = '*'

step-2  

vi /etc/postgresql/14/main# vi pg_hba.conf

# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer

step-3
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart

step-4
After restart your changes
create your required database and database username
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think in production you wana bother yourself changing any files. 
So, What you can do is temporarily make the username same to the username of your postgres which is usually postgres by passing command `sudo -i -u postgres` and then `psql`, now you successfully connected to postgres.

Answer (score 2):

**Depending on your use case and environment. For me, most of my environment is local. Just in case the above example fails to work. you can try this:**

> `Edit the pg_indent.conf file`

```
***$sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_ident.conf***
```

Add

```
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME         PG-USERNAME
user1           <computer-username>     <computer-username>
```

> **To find your computer user, you can use this command** `whoami, who, w ,who -q`. any of those should give your a hint of the current user

```
> So you can replace your username against <computer-username>. So your
SYSTEM_USERNAME & PG-USERNAME should be = your username
```

**Next**

> `*sudo nano pg_hba.conf*`

```
$sudo nano /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Add the changes to satisfy your usecase

```
*# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local    all             <Computer-username>                     peer map=user1
```

**So this allows you to login without specifying our password**

***Make sure to restart postgresql***

> `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart`

***After restart your changes
create your required database and database username***

Answer (score 1):

If the above solutions do not work, try this one! It seems that it is a connection problem; probably, your issue would resolve by specifying all connection parameters. The general form of the command could be like this:

```
pg_dump --dbname=<DB-NAME> --username=<USER-NAME-OF-DB-OWNER> --port=<USUALLY: 5432> --host=<USUALLY: 127.0.0.1> --password > <DUMP-NAME>.sql
```

In addition, you can use different parameters for the dumping process.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to, just switch to the postgres user on your system first. I appreciate that this requires you to have permission to do this, but it is worth mentioning as it is much more simple than messing with config - and if you are allowed to mess with the postgres config then you can probably do this anyway.

If you are logged in as root

```
su - postgres
```

if you are logged in as a user with sudo privileges

```
sudo su - postgres
```

- then your `psql` should just work with no parameters

If you have the similar problem where your database owner is not the default 'postgres', then the simple solution is to create a user whose name matches the database user e.g. 'mydatabase' and log in as that user (or switch to it as above)

```
adduser mydatabase
```

Optionally add that user to the privileged group if that's what you want (Ubuntu example below)

```
usermod -aG sudo mydatabase
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add param host,

for example like this `-h 127.0.0.1`

```bash
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U user -d database
pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U user -d database -f dump.sql
```