# Django Authentication error when connecting to local postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, wsl-2

I keep getting this error "password authentication failed for user postgres".
I am trying to launch a django server on my computer using WSL (ubuntu 20.04) to my local laptop postgres database.

I have my settings set correctly , i am able to connect to the psql from my ubuntu using, so the connection is fine. I set the pg_hba to trust postgres.

But when i try to run my django i get the same password authentication error.

Please help ,[my pg_hba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbAop.png),[wsl can connect using psql -U postgres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEHqJ.png),[django settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q8dE.png),[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSj4C.png),[pg_ident](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfFvg.png)

tried this didnt help

[psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres" (Ubuntu)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676009/psql-error-connection-to-server-on-socket-var-run-postgresql-s-pgsql-5432)

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the pg_hba? If 'trust' were in effect, you would not be getting that error, so it must not be in effect.  What do you get in the db server log file?

Comment: i did restart it.
Used the following commands
"sudo sudo systemctl restart postgresql@14-main.service" and 
"sudo service postgresql start" , several times. 
what is baffling me is ,
"psql -U postgres " command is working fine and i am able to connect to the database. So the connection is fine. Its django that is unable to connect

Comment: Your shown `psql` command uses the unix-domain socket, not the TCP stack.  to make them comparable, you should use `-h localhost` with it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. In pg_hba, method for 'postgres' user was initially set to trust, as such i didnt have a password set.

To make sure django database configuration works, the password must be present for the user 'postgres'

make sure u can access postgres from wsl
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4s7y.png)

check the password of the user with the command

```
SELECT rolname, rolpassword
FROM pg_authid
WHERE rolname = 'postgres';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zwj7.png)

Set the password

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD '12345678';
```

That should do it